# Can I reposition and/or split android keyboard?

Tags: android, keyboard, ime

I am writing a custom android IME, and would like the keyboard on the side of the display rather than the bottom (actually, I want the user to have options). If possible, I would like to split the keyboard into 2 or more parts, located around the display edges.

I have reviewed various complicated solutions which may need extensive cross-device testing.

Is there a simple (and reliable) way to do this, with say, XML layout?  I know Java, but not much about android layout.

Comment: Have you read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html ?

Comment: Yes, and I have a working IME at bottom of screen. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question, after much digging I think the answer is no, there is no simple way of moving the keyboard from the bottom of the display.  I have settled on a very small "keyboard" along the bottom, and then creating a mostly transparent popup view.  Not nearly as simple as what I was hoping for, but I think I can eventually get it to look the way I want.

Comment: How did you get a transparent popup view? I've tried everything I can think of, and my keyboard always has a white, opaque background.